# Difference between MANOVA and two-way ANOVA

Tags: anova, manova

I have read the articles of both of these statistical methods on wikipedia, and as far as I can tell they are used in the same cases. I could not tell in how far they work the same way, since the [two-way ANOVA article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-way_analysis_of_variance) is rather elliptic.

Could you tell me:

- Whether there is a difference between these two methods
- What the difference is
- What use cases is each method best suited for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a (one-way) MANOVA, you study the effect of a single categorical variable (e.g. treatment yes/no) on the averages of two or more continuous response variables (e.g. diastolic and systolic blood pressure).

In a two-way ANOVA, you study the effects of two categorical variables (e.g. treatment yes/no and and sex) on the average of a single continuous response variable (e.g. systolic blood pressure).